# My Winforms app doesn't connect to SQL Server 2000?

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2000

I have written  this code in my class file to connect to SQL Server 2000 but it doesn't work please help me!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;//to get dataset
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace CottonPurchase
{
    class Library
    {
        private OleDbConnection conn;//provides a connection string
        //that helps to connect to any database
        //command: helps to perform INSER/UPDATE/DELETE and SELECT 
        //statements
        private OleDbCommand cmd;
        //is used to generate SQL statements that helps you to
        //bind them to controls such as dta grid view control.
        private OleDbDataAdapter da;
        //DataSet helps you to store data retrieved from the database
        //temporarily so that you dont require to remain connected
        //with the database once the data is retrieved and stored
        //into the dataset. 
        private DataSet ds;

        //Data Reader is used to fetch records from a table 
        //using the command object.
        private OleDbDataReader dr;

        /**
         * Function: GetConnection
         * Parameter: Nil
         * ReturnType: bool
         * Description: This function returns true
         * if the connection succeeds and false if it fails.
         * */
        public bool GetConnection()
        {
            bool flag = false;
            try
            {
               conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=TANYA-PC; User ID=sa; Password=; Database=biore1");
               conn.Open();//it opens the connection to the database
               flag = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               flag = false;
            }

            return flag;
        }

    /**
    * Function Name: CloseConnection
    * Return Type: bool
    * Parameter: Nil
    * Description: This function closes any active connection
    * */
    public bool CloseConnection()
    {
        bool flag = false;

        try
        {
            conn.Close();//This statement closes the connection
            flag = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
    }

    /**
     * Function Name: ExecuteSQLStatement
     * Parameter: string
     * Return Type: bool
     * Description: This function passes the INSERT/UPDATE or
     * DELETE statement as a string parameter and returns true
     * if the statement succeeds and false if it fails.
     * */
    public bool ExecuteSQLStatement(string sql)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            //Command object is used to isert/update or delete
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            //ExecuteNonQuery function  is used for 
            //INSERT/UPDATE and DELETE only
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Performs the insertion/deletion or updation
            flag = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }

    /**
     * Function Name: GenerateID
     * Parameter: string
     * Return Type: int
     * Description: This function passes the table name as parameter
     * and returns a unique ID as a numeric value.
     * */
    public int GenerateID(string tablename)
    {
        int recordcount = 0;
        try
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*) from " + tablename, conn);
            //
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();//will fetch the result from the provided query and assign it to the data reader object
            dr.Read();//will move the record pointer to the first record

            recordcount = dr.GetInt32(0);

            recordcount++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return recordcount;
    }
}

}
```

The thing is that I'm using Windows authentication to log into my SQL Server?

Comment: **What error message are you seeing?** Please edit your question to include this information. Please edit to include only the lines of code relevant to your error.

Comment: If you are using Windows Auth, then why does your connection string specify a username and password?  You should use one or the other, not both.  And please take the time to format your code so we can read it.  Finally, you don't say what, if any, errors you are getting.

Comment: If you connect to SQL Server 2000 - why do you have `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` at the top of the file??  And what reason do you have to use `OleDbConnection` instead of the more appropriate `SqlConnection` for SQL Server ??

Comment: if you have a new question then please ask this separately, don't use the answers for this purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using windows auth to log in. According to your connection string you're using SQL Authentication to try and log in:

```
 conn = new OleDbConnection(
 "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=TANYA-PC; User ID=sa; Password=; Database=biore1");
```

I can tell because there is a user id and password in the connection string instead of trusted, SSPI or other arguments (specific to provider etc.) necessary to formulate a proper connection string with trusted credentials.For connection string help please take a look at [ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com), and then bookmark it.

(i'm not sure if you're aware but the password field is blank, at least in the example code.)

Comment: heyy thaanx but i figured it out!

Comment: @tanya: Good. Would you mind sharing the solution (you can answer and accept your own question) so that others might find it on SO and make use of it? Thanks!

Comment: hey can you please help me i dont know how to use grid view in winforms?? please help

Comment: Sure. Check out this tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database If it doesn't suit you try these google search results: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+binding+to+datagrid+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @paul please i need you help , i have a datagridview and i want to implement a search. i want to put a textbox above the gridview so everytime i put atleast a letter eg 'a' it searches for the items beginning from that letter. please help me do this

Comment: @PaulSasik  please i need you help , i have a datagridview and i want to implement a search. i want to put a textbox above the gridview so everytime i put atleast a letter eg 'a' it searches for the items beginning from that letter. please help me do this